# How can I use Mono<Boolean> as condition to call second method

Tags: spring-webflux, reactor

I'm trying to make a call to one service after checking a condition from another service in an iterative way, like so:

```
if (productService.isProductNotExcluded(product)){
    List<Properties> properties = propertiesService.getProductDetailProperties(product)
...
}
```

But since `isProductExcluded` is returning `Mono<Boolean>` I'm using this approach, which seems really odd:

```
Flux<Properties> properties = productService.isProductNotExcluded(productId)
     .filter(notExcluded -> notExcluded)
     .map(ok-> propertiesService.getProductDetailProperties(product))
     ...
```

Which is the correct way to deal with this kind of situation?

Comment: You could just make an if else statement in the `map` function

Comment: This not odd what you are doing. If you don't like it then you can use Thomas Andolf solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a predicate which returns a `Mono<Boolean>`, you can also use `filterWhen` which takes a publisher as a predicate. Something like this:

```
Flux<Properties> properties = Mono.just(productId)
.filterWhen(prodId -> productService.isProductNotExcluded(prodId))
.map(validProductId -> propertiesService.getProductDetailProperties(validProductId));
```

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing is not odd. I personally wouldn't return a boolean in a reactive function `Mono<Boolean>` if I can avoid it, but it's not wrong and sometimes you don't have a choice.

I personally would have an if/else statement in the map, for clarity. I would also change the name of the function, and rewrite the `isNot` part.

```
Flux<Properties> properties = productService.isExcluded(productId)
   .flatMap(isExcluded -> {
       if(!isExcluded)
         return propertiesService.getProductDetailProperties(product);
       else
         return mono.empty();
   });
```

This is matter of opinion and coding taste, but I find this to be a lot more readable, because you can read the code and understand it straight away. But this is a personal taste.

Comment: that should be a `flatMap`, I believe

Answer (score 0):

**all() operator can be used.**

According to the doc. all() Emits a single **boolean** **true** if `all values of this sequence match`

> Mono all(Predicate<? super T> predicate) {}

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.